# Implementing a CI/Deployment Pipeline for a Node app

Tags: node.js, docker, travis-ci, google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-registry

I will shortly be in the process of rewriting a node app with the intention of 
implementing Continuous Integration and TDD.

I also want to design and set up a deployment pipeline for development, staging, and production.

Currently I'm using Shipit to push changes to different instances that have pre-configured environments.  I've heard about deploying Docker containers with the needed environments, and I'd like to learn more about that.

I'm looking at TravisCI and for automated testing/builds, and from my understanding, one can push the Docker image to a registry after the build succeeds.

I'm also learning about scaling, and looking at a design for production that incorporates Google Cloud servers/services serving 3 clustered versions of the node app, a Redis cluster, and 2 PostgreSQL nodes, which each service being behind a load balancer.

I've heard of Kubernetes being used to manage and deploy containerized applications, but I'm curious on how it all fits together.

In my head I think that it would seem like the process would be as follows:

1. commit changes on dev machine - push to repository.
2. TravisCI builds and runs tests, (what about migrations and pushing changes to the postgreSQL service?), pushes to a Google Cloud Container Registry.
3. Log into the Google Container Engine and run the app with Kubernetes.
4. What about the Redis Cluster? The PostgreSQL nodes?

I apologize in advance if this question is lacking in clarity and knowledge, but I'm trying to learn more before I move along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered Google Cloud Container Builder? It's very easy to set up a [trigger](https://cloud.google.com/container-builder/docs/creating-build-triggers) from your Github repository, which would start a new build on changes (branch or tag).

As part of the build, you can push the new image to GCR.

And you could also [deploy to Kubernetes](https://gist.github.com/Philmod/e18056caac485549bb5339ffa4fd31b5) as part of the same build.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  I haven't looked into it, but I will now!  I'm still curious on how to deploy database changes as part of the build as well.

Comment: Are you talking about database schema change? I wouldn't recommend to deploy automatically production database changes with a build.